# I need to encrypt all PII data in all my SQL Server tables

Tags: sql-server

I need to encrypt all PII data in all my SQL Server tables.
Examples:
SSN
DOB

And they all have data in them. So, how can I encrypt existing data in a SQL Server table. So, I can run a script and encrypt all these attributes

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of considerations. First you need to convert existing data using some sort of script or a stored proc, Next you need to set up **triggers** so that all future changes to the fields are encrypted. Do not even consider setting this up to happen only from the application. This must be done in a trigger to ensure that data imports, manual backend changes, etc. also encrypt.

Next you need to set up the security so that only certain users are allowed to decrypt.  Security and process to get approval to get something decrypted should be documented. In considering decryption, consider what you use this information for. We use SSNs in reports to clients and to create tax documents. YOu need to make sure the processes to do these sort of things are modified to include decrypting the data. If decrypted data is produced in a file, you need to consider the security of the file location and how it will be transmitted to the user of the file.  You also need to make sure that security to the production databases is severely limited. If you use dev/QA UAT database and refresh the data from prod, the data in these fields should be further scrambled so that a person with access only to a lower environment cannot decrypt the data in the higher environment.

You also need to make a good copy of your database before you do this and then after encrypting a few values, decrypt them to make sure that they still have the same values.  That is part of your testing protocol.